# Forbid to add attributes to user-defined class in Python

Tags: python

When you create a user-defined class, you can, by default, dinamically add attributes to it just like in the next example:

```
# User defined class
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_att = 5

test = Test()
test.second_att = 11
print(test.__dict__)
```

```
{'first_att': 5, 'second_att': 11}
```

But built-in classes don't allow such a thing:

```
# Built-in class
str_example = 'Test string'

str_example.added_att = 5
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'added_att'
```

How can I modify my class Test so it doesn't allow it also?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First preventing the user to do a harmless thing is uncommon in Python. Builtin classes do no willingly forbid to add attributes, they simply have static *slots* instead of a dynamic `__dict__` to store their members, because it is simpler to do that when writing a Python class using the C API.

You can mimic that with Python classes by using a `__slots__` attribute. But beware, it is not really a *security* thing, because by default subclasses will receive a `__dict__` member and will allow dynamic attributes.

Demo:

```
class Test:
    __slots__ = ['first_att']
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_att = 5
test = Test()
test.second_att = 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'second_att'
```

But:

```
class TestChild(Test):
    pass

child = TestChild()
child.second_att = 7
```

without any exception...

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by overwriting the `__setattr__` method. As a very simple example for your case

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_att = 5

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key not in ("first_att",):  # allowed attributes
            raise AttributeError(f"Not allowed to set attribute {key}")
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
```

Note that you have to add an exception list here that holds the names of the attributes you want to be able to assign values to.

Answer (score 2):

You can define in your class the allowed attributes by adding `__slots__`.
In there put the names of the attributes you want. All other attributes won't be accepted.
For example try this:

```
# User defined class
class Test:
    __slots__ = ("fitst_att", "your_att_name")

    def __init__(self):
        self.first_att = 5

test = Test()
test.your_att_name = 11
print(test.__dict__)
# test.second_att = 11  ##this will rais an error
```